# How to access REST API of S/4HANA Cloud

Tags: api, rest, s4hana

I have a S/4HANA Cloud trial account, and trying to access REST APIs. I am getting "401 Not Authorized" error.
Is access to REST API not allowed for S/4HANA trial accounts? Is there a way to enable it? Or should I use some other userid for Basic Auth of REST APIs ? (I am trying same userid/password as the web browser)
Thank you.
sibendu

Comment: what exact API you are trying to use?

Comment: @Suncatcher - does it (API-based access) depend on which API? However, any of the functional api (e.g. SO, PO or anything else) is ok. My question is if such access cna be enabled for trial account.